# should I use "maintain" or "maintaining"?

Tags: infinitives

In the sentence below:

Whether it is of more importance to maintain old friends for a person than it is to make new friends.

Is it correct to use "maintain" as considering "maintain" is part of the infinitive "to maintain", or to use "maintaining" by looking on the preceding "to" as a proposition?

Essentially, I guess I don't know how to distinguish "to" as a preposition or part of the infinitive.

Comment: But your example isn't a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjective *important* allows for two functions of a following *to*:

1. [An infinitive](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/grammar-pattern/it-v-link-adj-to-inf_7), as in *it is important to wash your hands*; this expresses the 'theme' of what is important. This is often used in conjunction with *it is* at the beginning.
2. [A noun group](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/grammar-pattern/adj-to-n_8), as in *it is important to my parents that I wash my hands*; the noun group expresses the 'beneficiary' of the 'theme', which is a *that*-clause in this example.

In your example, the 'theme' is to maintain old friends, so it is clearly the first function: *maintain* is an infinitive form, so not part of a noun group, and the *to* is the infinitive marker, and not a preposition.

Comment: I have a further question:　If I change the sentence to "Whether it is of more importance maintaining old friends for a person than it is to make new friends." which I think is that I have changed the infinitive to a noun group. Is that correct?

Comment: @CharlieWang Yes, it's an ing-clause, which replaces the to-infinitive. The two are functionally equivalent.